# SMTP Friendly Name in 3 different places -- still doesn't show

Tags: c#, .net, email, iis, smtp

I have specified the SMTP friendly name in my code (`new MailAddress("ActualFrom", "FriendlyFrom")`) and in my `web.config` file, but once the email gets sent, the friendly name is not there.  In all these instances, I've tried both `"Friendly Name" <ActualFrom@email.com>` (with quotes) as well as `Friendly Name <ActualFrom@email.com>` (without quotes), but neither makes a difference; both show up in inbox as being from the email address, no friendly name.

**UPDATE:** I moved my code to a different server, and it started working.  Turns out my code was fine

(ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻  So what would cause this to happen??

Answer (score 3):

Assuming information is being correctly retrieved from your configuration file, this works with no need for any additional settings:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var message = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(fromAddress, "Friendly Name"),
            Subject = "Test Friendly Name",
            Body = "Friendly name works !"
        };

        message.To.Add(recipient);

        var client = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = username,
                Password = password
            }
        };

        client.Send(message);
    }
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I just tried the very same code using account / host information from our domain and it works just as good:

[image]

Comment: I'm using on-premises smtp, not gmail. Could the problem be my smtp?

Comment: It is possible... although I'd think it is unlikely. Looking at the print screen of your config file, it looks like your _friendly name_ and the email itself are bundled together, and I'm not sure how you're handling that in your code. Also, your `MailMessage` is setting both `From` and `Sender`. I would try one or the other but not both at the same time. Could you please try my code exactly like it is, just replacing my values with yours, without using any values from the config file? Please populate it manually first. You need to narrow down where the problem actually is.  Let me know.

Comment: Also, please make `UseDefaultCredentials = false` and then explicitly use credentials associated with the same email you're setting the friendly name for.

Comment: Sure, I will try.  I need a gmail account though first, right?

Comment: Can't you try with this account you're working with ?

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: Welp I tried moving my project to a different server on our network, and now it's working.  Turns out my code was fine (ノಠ益ಠ)ノ彡┻━┻

Answer (score 3):

You could try an encoded markup in your `from` attribute.

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="Friendly Displayname &lt;your.mail@domain.com&gt;">
```

I know this still does not explain why it works on another server without this format.

Answer (score 2):

Use the overload constructor of the MailAddress like you have in your code.

I would remove the Friendly Name specified in the Configuration. The configuration setting should just have the Email Address listed.

**UPDATE:**

I wrote a sample code with the exact same settings and sent email through our internal mail relay. The email was sent fine and did display the friendly name in the sent email.

The one thing I would check is any network policy if any is in place within your network to trim the friendly name display while sending mail internally/externally.